# htaccess Cross-Origin Resource Sharing on one site with multiple domains

Tags: css, wordpress, .htaccess, fonts

I'm sure this question has been asked on here before but every solution that I've found has left me in the dark.

We have 3 domains: .com, .org and .eu
all these domainnames lead to the same website on the same server.
Our wordpress site is configured to run on the .com domain in the settings of wordpress.

When our theme is trying to load some fonts when visiting our .com domain everything is shown as it should be.
When visiting our .org domain all font icons fail to load due to this error:

> Font from origin 'http://www.oursite.com' has been blocked from
>   loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://www.oursite.org' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

I've tried editing our .htaccess file but this hasn't been of any use.
the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

(I know allowing * isn't the best option but this is just a test, it will be changed to the .com domainname when it works.)

Thanks in advance,
Yentel

Comment: can't you just use a relative path?

Comment: The problem is that it's not our theme but a premium theme that my employer asked me to buy.